# Spring boot fat jar cannot read file from absolute path defined in application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So i have a Spring boot fat jar that has a config that needs to load a `.pem` file from an absolute path defined in `application.properties` file.

I defined the path like this:

```
security.jwt.public-key=/opt/samara/staging.pem
```

The usage is like this:

```
    @Value("\${security.jwt.public-key}")
    lateinit var publicKey: Resource
```

Here is the directory structure:

```
root@samara:/opt/samara# ls -lsh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  44M Nov 27 07:50 app.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.0K Nov 27 07:53 staging.pem
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.2K Nov 27 08:29 application.properties
```

But when i tried to run it like this:

```
root@samara:/opt/samara# java -jar app.jar
```

it failed with this:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/opt/samara/staging.pem]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:158) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
```

Actually, i copied those files from another machine and it runs perfectly in that machine but i don't know why it failed in the new machine. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your `publicKey` property is being used to retrieve a resource from the `ServletContext` rather than to load something straight from the filesystem. Can you share the code where the property is being used?

Comment: It interprets the path as a servlet-context resource. Not as a file resource. Prepending the prefix `file:` should probably fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources

I changed the path definition to:

```
security.jwt.public-key=file:/opt/samara/staging.pem
```

And it worked!